# What is the easiest way in C# to trim a newline off of a string?

Tags: c#, string

I want to make sure that _content does not end with a NewLine character:

```
_content = sb.ToString().Trim(new char[] { Environment.NewLine });
```

but the **above code doesn't work** since Trim seems to not have an overloaded parameter for a collection of strings, only characters.

**What is the simplest one-liner to remove an Enivronment.Newline from the end of a string?**

Comment: btw, you probably want TrimEnd

Comment: These days it's just `.Trim()` or `.TrimEnd()`

Answer (score 311, accepted):

The following works for me.

```
sb.ToString().TrimEnd( '\r', '\n' );
```

or

```
sb.ToString().TrimEnd( Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray());
```

Comment: very concise and deals with the \r\n issue, nice

Comment: While trimming ANY combination of characters that make up a new line char(s) does address underlying problem and the spirit of the question, it also leaves a potential for unwanted functionality in the general sense. In a file processing senario I could see a need for leaving the first \n intact in a string of HeresALineForUnixToBeFedFromWindows\n\r\n.  While more verbose, John Skeet's answer is probably the best and Scott Weinstein's ReadLine is also more "accurate" (albeit maybe with a bit more overhead)

Comment: TrimEnd() is already doing the Job without any Parameters! http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.string.trimend(v=vs.110).aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.char.iswhitespace(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Markus Thanks I found this because I do not want this behavior but was experiencing it. I was under the impression \n was not a white space but it is and .TrimEnd and .Trim clear all [white space](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664665%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) characters natively

Comment: Some details based on what @Markus shared.
If this method returns true the character is removed. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char.iswhitespace

You can test here. https://dotnetfiddle.net/OQKFmH

Just change it to the character you are wondering about.

Answer (score 66):

`.Trim()` removes `\r\n` for me (using .NET 4.0).

Comment: Yes, it does remove `\r\n` surprisingly. So far, I was under the impression that `.Trim()` only removes spaces from both sides.

Comment: The change was introduced in .NET 4.0. See "Notes to Callers" at [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/System.String.Trim?view=netframework-4.8)

Answer (score 19):

How about:

```
public static string TrimNewLines(string text)
{
    while (text.EndsWith(Environment.NewLine))
    {
        text = text.Substring(0, text.Length - Environment.NewLine.Length);
    }
    return text;
}
```

It's somewhat inefficient if there are multiple newlines, but it'll work.

Alternatively, if you don't mind it trimming (say) `"\r\r\r\r"` or `"\n\n\n\n"` rather than just `"\r\n\r\n\r\n"`:

```
// No need to create a new array each time
private static readonly char[] NewLineChars = Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray();

public static string TrimNewLines(string text)
{
    return text.TrimEnd(NewLineChars);
}
```

Comment: Probably the most accurate solution, but not a one-liner :-)

Answer (score 9):

Use the Framework. The ReadLine() method has the following to say:

> A line is defined as a sequence of
>   characters followed by a line feed
>   ("\n"), a carriage return ("\r") or a
>   carriage return immediately followed
>   by a line feed ("\r\n"). The string
>   that is returned does not contain the
>   terminating carriage return or line
>   feed.

So the following will do the trick

```
_content = new StringReader(sb.ToString()).ReadLine();
```

Comment: Elegant yes, but not easy to understand for others reading this line. Needs an explaining comment (in the same line of course to remain a one-liner :))

Comment: Does not when the string has more than one line and you only want to remove the last empty line.

Answer (score 7):

What about

```
_content = sb.ToString().Trim(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray());
```

Comment: That doesn't do *quite* the same thing - it'll trim "abc\n\n\n\n\n" for example, even if Environment.NewLine is crlf

Comment: Declare it as a feature :-) I like the solution.

Answer (score 5):

```
_content = sb.TrimEnd(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray());
```

This will of course remove "\r\r\r\r" as well as "\n\n\n\n" and other combinations.
And in "enviroments" where NewLine is other than "\n\r" you might get some strange behaviors :-)

But if you can live with this then I belive this is the most effectiv way to remove new line characters at the end of a string.

Answer (score 3):

How about just:

```
string text = sb.ToString().TrimEnd(null)
```

That will pull all whitespace characters from the end of the string -- only a problem if you wanted to preserve non-newline whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

Somewhat of a non-answer, but the easiest way to trim a newline off of a string is to not have the newline on the string in the first place, by making sure it is is never seen by your own code.  That is, by using native functions which remove the newline.  Many stream and file/io methods will not include the newline if you ask for output line by line, though it may be necessary to wrap something in a `System.IO.BufferedStream`.

Things like `System.IO.File.ReadAllLines` can be used in place of `System.IO.File.ReadAllText` most of the time, and `ReadLine` can be used instead of `Read` once you are working with the right type of stream (e.g. `BufferedStream`).

Answer (score 0):

As Markus pointed out TrimEnd is doing the job now. I needed to get line feeds and white space from both ends of string in Windows Phone 7.8 environment. After having chased different more complex options my problem was solved by using Trim() only - passed the following tests nicely

```
   [TestMethod]
    [Description("TrimNewLines tests")]
    public void Test_TrimNewLines()
    {
        Test_TrimNewLines_runTest("\n\r     testi    \n\r", "testi");
        Test_TrimNewLines_runTest("\r     testi    \r", "testi");
        Test_TrimNewLines_runTest("\n     testi    \n", "testi");
        Test_TrimNewLines_runTest("\r\r\r\r\n\r     testi   \r\r\r\r \n\r", "testi");
        Test_TrimNewLines_runTest("\n\r  \n\n\n\n   testi äål.,    \n\r", "testi äål.,");
        Test_TrimNewLines_runTest("\n\n\n\n     testi  ja testi  \n\r\n\n\n\n", "testi  ja testi");
        Test_TrimNewLines_runTest("", "");
        Test_TrimNewLines_runTest("\n\r\n\n\r\n", "");
        Test_TrimNewLines_runTest("\n\r \n\n \n\n", "");
    }

    private static void Test_TrimNewLines_runTest(string _before, string _expected)
    {
        string _response = _before.Trim();
        Assert.IsTrue(_expected == _response, "string '" + _before + "' was translated to '" + _response + "' - should have been '" + _expected + "'");
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

I had to remove the new lines all over the text. So I used:

```
            while (text.Contains(Environment.NewLine))
            {
                text = text.Substring(0, text.Length - Environment.NewLine.Length);
            }
```

Comment: This will be a disaster if text contains NewLine(s) that is not in the end.