# Can't trim newline off variable in c#

Tags: c#, newline

On the post [What is the easiest way in C# to trim a newline off of a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038031/what-is-the-easiest-way-in-c-sharp-to-trim-a-newline-off-of-a-string) something that looks the same to me works for them but it leaves the new line at the beginning of my string. No errors, it just doesn't trim anything.

```
public formWords()
   {
   foreach (string word in someArray)
        {
            fileList += Environment.NewLine + word;
        }
        fileList.Trim(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray());
        txtHolder.Text = fileList;
    }
```

What did I do wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are two `char`'s in a `NewLine` in Windows... `\r` and `\n`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this code:

```
fileList.ToString().Trim( '\r', '\n' );
```

Or use code ([jon skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038031/what-is-the-easiest-way-in-c-sharp-to-trim-a-newline-off-of-a-string))

```
public static string TrimNewLines(string text)
{
    while (text.EndsWith(Environment.NewLine))
    {
        text = text.Substring(0, text.Length - Environment.NewLine.Length);
    }
    return text;
}
private static readonly char[] NewLineChars = Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray();

public static string TrimNewLines(string text)
{
    return text.TrimEnd(NewLineChars);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for being so quick. I tried the first suggestion. It didn't work. The second looks like it would trim from the end, but what I'm trying to cut is at the start.

Comment: Can trim word then trim fileList>?

Comment: Excellent! Thanks. That makes sense now what I did wrong. Thumbs up to you good sir.

Answer (score 0):

```
fileList +=word + Environment.NewLine;
```